# What’s the difference ‘refer to somebody/something’ and ‘to describe’?

Tags: difference

In Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary (9th Edition), the definition of **refer to somebody/ something** is

> to describe or be connected to something

So, What’s the difference between them?

Comment: When a dictionary provides an explanation for a word, you cannot then ask: what's the difference between them. One explains the other. Also, with all due respect, whatever your native language is, a basic bilingual dictionary would give you translations for the word refer and the word describe and connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, I don't like that definition. That doesn't seem to really define the term.

**Describing** something means listing a series of features so that somebody else can recognise them. I might describe myself as a short, fat male, with glasses and a close-cropped beard.

**Refer to** has a number of related meanings/uses. At the core, it's about directing someone to another place or meaning where they can get more information. In fact, it's what you would use *instead* of describing something. That might mean mentioning something's name, or telling someone where they can find a definition or answer. For example:

> "I spent my afternoon feeding ducks."
>
> "Ducks? You mean medium-sized waterfowl with broad bills that go quack?"
>
> "Yes, that's what I'm **referring to**."

'Duck' is a reference - a word used to point to a broad definition.

Similarly, a **reference** is a comment or phrase with a deeper meaning for those who recognise it:

> Nick Fury: I'd like to know how Loki used it to turn two of the sharpest men I know into his personal flying monkeys.
>
> Thor: Monkeys? I do not understand.
>
> Steve Rogers: I do! I understood that **reference**.

In this case, the reference is to the old *Wizard of Oz* film, in which the Wicked Witch is served by a collection of winged monkeys; the term has become shorthand in popular culture for a villain's henchmen. Steve Rogers has seen the film, so he understood what Fury was talking about.

Another use:

> Before changing any fuses, ensure power is fully disconnected. For details on disconnecting the power system, **refer to** page 95 of your user manual

This line might be seen in a set of instructions; rather than repeating how to perform a particular task every time it's needed, you would have a single location in the manual that describes the task, and other processes would simply refer back to that location.

**Refer** is also used when a professional is passing a case on to another professional, especially in medicine. If you visit your doctor and they decide you need surgery, you would be **referred** to a surgeon.

A **reference book** is one, like a dictionary or an encyclopedia, that is not intended to be read from beginning to end, but arranged so that you can find a particular piece of information easily.

In all cases, then, **refer to** indicates pointing one to where more detailed information can be found.